# Using firebase with webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

I currently have firebase and my javascript files, which use firebase loaded through `<script>`. Clearly, this is not a very good way of doing it.

I want to be able to use webpack with my front end javascript, but I'm facing some issues:

My layout is like this:

```
user/
    index.js
    file1.js
    file2.js
```

`file1.js` and `file2.js`are included into `index.js` **but** all files use firebase.

My question is do I need to include firebase, and all of my requirements, like firestore, functions and messaging. into every single file, or can I include it once somewhere, to be used throughout all files?

When I include it in every file, I get an error saying that firebase could not be found.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Firebase package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) on npm. In the instructions for using webpack, you can simply import the modules you need into `file1.js` and `file2.js`.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
var app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
```

Note that the documentation says to only include the features you need (to not bloat your bundle.js).

```
// This import loads the firebase namespace along with all its type information.
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

// These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

// In your case, include Firestore in the files you use them in.
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Comment: That is what I am currently doing. Do I need to import the config into each file?

Comment: So create a new file init-firebase.js, initialize the firebase app; and then include it in your main entry.js file. See this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#additional_setup_options

Comment: I know how to set it up, but if you look at my question, it does not work.